# List slicing issues in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

This code seems like it should work. It sums up the number of words that are "striped" (letter-consonant-letter-etc.) and then returns the sum. However when I test it with `print (striped("My name is ...") )` it only counts `my` and `is` and gives me a sum of 2 instead of 3... why is `name` missing?

```
VOWELS = "AEIOUY"
CONSONANTS = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ"


def striped(text):

    my_sum = 0
    text = text.replace(".", " ").replace(",", " ").split()
    vowels = VOWELS.lower()
    consonants = CONSONANTS.lower()

    for word in text:
        word = word.lower()
        if ((word[::2] in vowels and word[1::2] in consonants)\
        or (word[::2] in consonants and word[1::2] in vowels))\
        and len(word) > 1:
            print (word)
            my_sum += 1

    return my_sum
```

Comment: also don't use `sum`! shadows the builtin

Comment: Ok, now that is changed also! still not working... and I've always used sum for this purpose, and so far it has given me no problems...?

Comment: you should have fixed the indentation.

Comment: Again cut and paste error... fixed now

Comment: well, your `return` statement is till not indented.

Comment: fixed again, wow ctr-c and ctr-v shouldnt be this hard

Comment: `from string import ascii_uppercase; CONSONANTS=''.join(c for c in ascii_uppercase if c not in vowels)`

Comment: @kojiro what are you doing over there? sorry n00b here

Comment: why is `my` considered to conform and `y` in  `"AEIOUY"`?

Comment: "y" is often considered a vowel @PadraicCunningham

Comment: nvm, I forgot you were checking both slices

Comment: @ejLev Oh, sorry, I was just pointing out that if you have a set of things you can generate the complementary set rather than hard coding it. In other words, if you have a set of vowels, the set of consonants is just the complementary set (in the universe of uppercase ascii letters). So you can generate it, instead of hard-coding it. This has more value when the sets are larger. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. However this actually comes off a code teaching site so for the challenge they started me off with those two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with lists. The problem with your code is that words longer than two characters return a substring when you use `[::2]` rather than single characters that are tested whether they are contained in `vowels` / `constants`.
By converting it to a list first, you can check every item of the list whether it is contained in the according set of characters.

```
VOWELS = "AEIOUY"
CONSONANTS = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ"


def striped(text):

    my_sum = 0
    text = text.replace(".", " ").replace(",", " ").split()
    vowels = VOWELS.lower()
    consonants = CONSONANTS.lower()

    for word in text:
        word = word.lower()

        if ((all(c in vowels for c in list(word[::2]))\
            and all(c in consonants for c in list(word[1::2])))\
        or (all(c in consonants for c in list(word[::2]))\
            and all(c in vowels for c in list(word[1::2]))))\
        and len(word) > 1:
            print (word)
            my_sum += 1

    return my_sum

print striped("My name is")
```

Comment: There needs to be an additional parentheses in there isolating the `and` statement from the `or`

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, however i still don't totally understand the whole `(all(c in vowels for c in list(word[::2])` any chance you could explain that briefly part by part?

Comment: Sure, let's start with `list(word[::2])`. Assuming the word is 'name', `[::2]` returns 'nm', which would not be in vowels since the whole string is tested and not its individual characters. That's why it is converted to a list first. `for c in list(word[::2])` by that means iterates over every character (`c`) of the word. Every character is checked individually whether it is contained in `vowels`. `all()` returns true if all elements of the iterable are true, in this case `c in vowels` in combination with the in-line for loop. See also https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `set.issubset()` instead.

```
VOWELS = "AEIOUY"
CONSONANTS = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ"

def striped(text):

    my_sum = 0
    text = text.replace(".", " ").replace(",", " ").split()
    vowels = set(c for c in VOWELS.lower())
    consonants = set(c for c in CONSONANTS.lower())

    for word in text:
        word = word.lower()
        if ((set(word[::2]).issubset(vowels) and set(word[1::2]).issubset(consonants))\
        or (set(word[::2]).issubset(consonants) and set(word[1::2]).issubset(vowels)))\
        and len(word) > 1:
            print (word)
            my_sum += 1
    return my_sum        

striped('My name is...')
```

The reason it works for `my` and `is` is that they are two char words, so you are checking if if `m` is in the string of constants, and if `y` is in the string of vowels, which works.  For longer words like `name`, then clearly `nm` is not in the string of sonsonants, so it fails.

---

Instead, you should use sets.  Essentially, you want to find if  `set(['n','m'])` is a subset of the set of consonants.

Comment: The problem with `set` is that you will have every letter just once, so it won't work for words that have some characters that occur more than once. You can instead use `list`.

Comment: This doesn't work though, because now i just tried it with striped("balllllllllll") and it gave me a `my_sum` of 1 when it should clearly be 0

Comment: You should include a set of test value to your original question, @ejLev

Comment: @EspartaPalma what do you mean by that?

Comment: Add on your post the values to test:
striped("My name is...") --> 3
striped("ballllllllll") --> 0
....

Comment: the ballllll was just off the top of my head trying to think why sets wouldnt work

Comment: I tried `striped("balllllllllll")`, which returned 0 for me.  Did you see my edit?